# Error event thrown for audio object in IE, yet it plays the audio?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, audio

This is my code:

```
<audio preload="auto" volume="1.0">
    <source type="audio/mpeg" src="path/to/file.mp3" />
</audio>
```

Using Javascript I get the `<audio>`-element as a variable, and set an error handler:

```
audioElement.onerror = function()
{
    alert('Error: ' + audioElement.error.code);
};
```

As soon as the `<audio>`-element is added to the DOM-tree, and after the audio is preloaded, the error gets thrown.
The alert box shows: `Error: 4` which means: `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

However, when clicking the playButton:

```
playButton.onclick = function()
{
    audioElement.play();
};
```

The sound plays as it should, and does not seem to be any problem. Why is the error thrown in the first place? Should I simply ignore the error if its code is 4?

*I can hardly find any documentation on specific cases in which this error is being thrown, that is why I ask this question. I hope somebody knows the answer here!*

Comment: which version of IE you are using?

Comment: I tested this in IE11 (but I think IE10 also had same problem, not sure).